# flutter login with telephone number

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

I have a problem and i can't solve it.

[image]
[image]

after i tap verify button (second img), it return first photo and that's it, like navigator.pop() function.

I have function which provides sign in with telephone number, here:

```
Future<void> signInWithTelephoneNumber({String phoneNumber}) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(phoneNumber: phoneNumber,isInProgress: true, errorMessage: ""));

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: "+9$phoneNumber",
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print("Successsssssssssssssssssss");
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
          emit(state.copyWith(errorMessage: "The provided phone number is not valid."));
        }
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
        String smsCode = '123456';

        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );

    emit(state.copyWith(phoneNumber: "",isInProgress: false, errorMessage: ""));
  }
```

when i click sign in button, it goes verification page (chapcta page), after i verify the image, it gives this error:

```
 Notifying id token listeners about user ( RID5Hq65CCcj1hXgyvVosA6QKbo1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 2708): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( RID5Hq65CCcj1hXgyvVosA6QKbo1 ).
E/flutter ( 2708): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

what should i do ? How can i solve this problem ? I use this link for source : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/

Comment: The problem is not in PhoneAuth. You are being logged-in successfully, it's what happens afterwards. Something is being called on a `null` value. But from your debug console, it says that you are authenticated. Post what happens after this snippet, this one should be okay.

Comment: i have updated the img, after i tap verify button, it behaves like navigator.pop() method. that's it

Comment: You cannot just enter 123456.  The user must fill in the code they received via SMS.  You have to get a code from the user.

Comment: @TheTahaan when and how ? could u help me

Comment: anyone ? help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used showDialog and i provide input for sms code. thx